# Card io on Android 6: No implementation found for boolean nUseX86

Tags: android, cardio

I am using [Card io](https://github.com/card-io) Android SDK in my app.

Everything was working fine until I moved to start building on Android 6 (M) (Target SDK 23 )

This is the log error I am getting

```
D/card.io:     nUseNeon(): true
D/card.io:     nUseTegra():false
E/art: No implementation found for boolean io.card.payment.CardScanner.nUseX86() (tried Java_io_card_payment_CardScanner_nUseX86 and Java_io_card_payment_CardScanner_nUseX86__)
E/card.io: Failed to load native library: No implementation found for boolean io.card.payment.CardScanner.nUseX86() (tried Java_io_card_payment_CardScanner_nUseX86 and Java_io_card_payment_CardScanner_nUseX86__)
I/card.io: Processor not Supported. Skipping camera.
```

Looks like the error comes from `No implementation found for boolean io.card.payment.CardScanner.nUseX86()`

I heard that there was many modification to the camera API in Android M, anything I can do to fix this?

Thanks